# Поиск ключа массива в массиве js

Tags: javascript, json

подскажите, пжл
есть два json файла
сравниваю в них значение id, если нахожу закидываю в новый массив - здесь всё ок.
Но проблема, как мне занести в массив данные, которые не были найдены?
например в 1 файле 10 записей, во втором 5
нашёл 5 записей в 1 файле, добавил в новый массив (сейчас так)
а надо еще добавить не найденные 5 значений

````
var unique = [];
for(var i = 0; i < jsonContent.length; i++)
{
    for(var j = 0; j < jsonContent2.length; j++)
    { // j < is missed;
        if(jsonContent[i].id == jsonContent2[j].id)
        {
            //minus = jsonContent[i].cost-jsonContent2[i].cost
            jsonContent[i].diff = jsonContent2[j].cc
            unique.push(jsonContent[i].diff); //jsonContent[i].cost-jsonContent2[j].cost2
            //jsonContent[i].diff=jsonContent[i].id
        break; //jsonContent2[j].cost2-jsonContent[i].cost
        }
    }
}



for (let i = 0; i < unique.length; i++) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(jsonContent[i]));//.toFixed(2)
}```
````

Comment: Занести в массив данные которые не были найдены? Эм, что...

Comment: ну у вас есть if, который проверяет есть ли совпадение, так допишите else и там добавляйте то, что не совпало

Comment: @Alexandr но тут 2 цикла, и в выборку будут попадать все несовпадения

Comment: а какие несовпадения вам нужны?

Comment: если из 2 массива ключ id не находится в 1 массиве, например
a1 = [1,2,3,5];

Answer (score 0):

Возможно вам поможет это.

```js
const idUsers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const idProject = [2, 3, 4]; 
idUsers.forEach(id => {
   if(idProject.includes(id)) { 
     console.log(id, 'true')
   } 

   else { 
    console.log(id, 'false')
   }
})
```